# AngularJS Build dynamically navigation with dynamic data

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make navigation with sub navigation. 
All navigation data i get with AJAX. 
I can have infinity subitems. navigation items has different types some of them can have subitems other not. And i have do display all parents in menu something like:

- Top level 1
- Top level 2
- Top level...
- Top level X

When i click on **Top level 1** i'll see:

- Top level 1

  - sublevel 1
  - sublevel 2
  - sublevel ...
  - sublevel X

Then if i'll click on **sublevel 2** i'll see:

- Top level 1

  - sublevel 2

    - sub sublevel ...
    - sub sublevel X

etc.

My directive html:

```
<div class="leftNav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked topLevel" role="tablist">
        <li class="title"><a>Sports</a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="titleTop in leftNavData track by titleTop.id" ng-show="titleTop.id == activeNavId || activeNavId == undefined ">
            <a ng-click="getSubItemData(titleTop.id)">{{titleTop.name}}</a>
            <ul class="subitems nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
                <li class="subitem" ng-repeat="subItem in subNavData" ng-show="subItem.parents[0].id == activeNavId">
                <a class="sublink">{{subItem.name}}{{subItem.type}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
controllers.controller('leftNavCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'leftNavDataService', 'CONST_DATA',
    function($scope, $http, leftNavDataService) {
        leftNavDataService.getNavigationData().then(function(data) {
            $scope.leftNavData = data;
            // console.log($scope.leftNavData);
        });

        $scope.getSubItemData = function(id) {
            leftNavDataService.getSubNavData(id).then(function(data) {
                $scope.subNavData = data;
                console.log($scope.subNavData);
                if ($scope.activeNavId == id) {
                    $scope.activeNavId = undefined;
                } else {
                    $scope.activeNavId = id;
                }
            });
        }

    }
])
```

My Service:

```
services.factory('leftNavDataService', function($http) {
    return {
        getNavigationData: function() {
            //return the promise directly.
            return $http({
                url: '/api/sports',
                method: 'GET',
            }).then(function(result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        }, 

        getSubNavData: function(id) {
            //return the promise directly.
            return $http({
                url: '/api/competitions/' + id,
                method: 'GET',
            }).then(function(result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How i can build such navigation?

Comment: Usually UL>A+LI>UL>A+LI structure is used.

Comment: i use such structure.
added my html to question.

Comment: Please better clarify your question: do you need controller implementation? If yes, please show the code you wrote just now...

Comment: added to description